# how do I find the php session start timestamp

Tags: php, session, timestamp, global-variables

I recall reading somewhere recently that you can obtain the server session start-time in timestamp format of the exact time a php session started for a user, but I cannot find this article again.

What I do not want is the request time (ie the time the `'REQUEST_TIME'`) or the "current timestamp" as of the execution of `date()` because (if I understand these correctly) they will change for each request and each script execution.

What I want is the time that the session was initiated on the server, and this logically can only be one moment in time.

There was apparently a was of retrieving this information.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should do a bookmark or blog about it if you found something useful in the internet. Then it's easier to find it again later on.

Comment: I know I know. I didn't find it that interesting at the time... it must have planted the seed though and now I pay the price.

Answer (score 8):

what's wrong with:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['started'])) {
    $_SESSION['started'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly this is the request time for the last http request. For example if the user has navigated to several pages it will capture the request time of the last navigation. Please orrect me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: @T9b: You are wrong. The time is only set once - when $_SESSION['started'] is not set. Then when set, it is untouched, so always the starting time.

Comment: Sorry, I was not considering the conditional statement. However my question is when the session was started on the server, not when the request began on the client. In theory the http request start time is logically before the session starts. What I'm after is the time as delivered by the server, not the client.

Comment: you can change `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` to `time()` I don't know why @hekre changed my answer maybe he can explain :)

Comment: Sure ;) - Both are actually more or less identical, however, `time()` needs a function call and returns *current* time, where as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` returns the request time, that is when PHP started (and is no function call), see http://php.net/manual/function.time.php

Comment: Maybe, but still I would vote for `time()` :D don't think one call per session would change something here.. but actually that depends on what he really needs..

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['start_time']))
{
    $str_time = time();
    $_SESSION['start_time'] = $str_time;
}

echo $_SESSION['start_time'];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a shortest answer

```
$_SESSION['started'] = (!isset($_SESSION['started'] ? time() : $_SESSION['started']);
```

Comment: or more short `$_SESSION['start']=@$_SESSION['start']?:time();` in **PHP7+**